# infinite loop when dispatching in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I have a Profile component that is loaded by react-router (path="profile/:username") and the component itself looks like this:

```
...
import { fetchUser } from '../actions/user';

class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { username } = this.props;
    this.fetchUser(username);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { username } = nextProps.params;
    this.fetchUser(username);
  }
  fetchUser(username) {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchUser(username));
  }
  render() {...}
}

export default connect((state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    username: ownProps.params.username,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
  };
})(Profile);
```

And the fetchUser action looks like this (redux-api-middleware):

```
function fetchUser(id) {
  let token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/api/users/${id}`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'x-access-token': token },
      types: [FETCH_USER_REQUEST, FETCH_USER_SUCCESS, FETCH_USER_FAILURE]
    }
  }
}
```

The reason I added componentWillReceiveProps function is to react when the URL changes to another :username and to load that users profile info. At a first glance everything seems to work but then I noticed while debugging that componentWillReceiveProps function is called in a infinite loop and I don't know why. If I remove componentWillReceiveProps then the profile doesn't get updated with the new username but then I have no loops problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `componentWillReceiveProps` is in an infinite loop because calling `fetchUser` will dispatch an action that will update the Props.

Add a comparison to check if the specific prop changes before dispatching the action.
**EDIT:**

In **React 16.3+** `componentWillReceiveProps` will be slowly **deprecated**.

> It is **recommended** to use `componentDidUpdate` in place of `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.params.username !== prevProps.params.username) {
    dispatch(fetchUser(username));
  }
}
```

See https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data-when-props-change

Comment: I understand now. The reducer for FETCH_USER_SUCCESS stored som user data which my Profile component was connecting over (which I forgot to add to my code above when writing the question). So the flow was componentWillReceiveProps --> dispatcher --> reducer updates data that Profile connects on --> componentWillReceiveProps is called again and it all starts over. I think I will need to move the code for route changes somewhere else to avoid this loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Try adding a condition to compare the props. If your component needs it.

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
 if(nextProps.value !== this.props.value)
  dispatch(action()) //do dispatch here 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have react routes with some path params like profile/:username, 
You can simply compare the **props.location.pathname**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){    
    if(nextProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname){
          dispatch()
        }
 }
```